# My GCP App is getting deployed and accessible through link. But its not getting opened, when using iframes?

Tags: angularjs, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, dialogflow-es, webhooks

My Angular app which uses dialogflow is deployed on Google App engine and working fine 
[here.](http://wrapper-eleqep.uc.r.appspot.com)
I also added a subdomain to access it.

Now when I try to add this in an iframe as follows,

Following error message is shown.

> classic.aim-tech.net is blocked
>   classic.aim-tech.net refused to connect.
>
> ERR_BLOCKED_BY_RESPONSE

I think its really related to a webpage in local file or http server accessing a https app.
How to resolve this error?

Answer (score 1):

The last line of https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/dialogflow-chatbot/blob/master/angular-ui/app.yaml#L52 causes this.

```
X-Frame-Options: DENY
```

You should remove (not recommended for prod environments) or modify this HTTP Response Header property.